# How can I assign random numbers using a loop and if else statement?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to quickly assign random numbers to a variable based off of the user input from previously.

Right now, I have the user input a number between 0-10. I want to use that inputed number to then randomly generate another number.

Currently, I am doing an if/ else if statement for each player.

```
function skill() {
   if (s[0] == 0) {
     s[0] = randomNumber(2,6);
   } else if (s[0] == 1) {
     s[0] = randomNumber(3,7);
   }

  }
});
```

I could do a if else statement for each player which would take like 20 lines. Is there a more efficient way to gather variables based off of the user inputed number?

Comment: Can you describe the logic of how the range is chosen based on the input?

Comment: Can you explain better what is the user input for? In the example given you put **2, 6** and **3,7** why?

Comment: `s` should be passed in as an argument to `skill`, which needs to be rename to clarify intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a general For loop to iterate through each element of the array for your skill logic.  Alternatively, you can use the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to execute the logic on each element in the array.  Below is an example based off your code.

**FOR Loop**

```
const s = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0];

function skill() {
 for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i] == 0) {
     s[i] = getRandomInt(2,6);
   } else if (s[i] == 1) {
     s[i] = getRandomInt(3,7);
   }
   console.log(s[i]);
  }  

};

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

skill();
```

**ForEach Function Alternative**

```
function skill() {
  s.forEach( function(i) {

    if (s[i] == 0) {
     s[i] = getRandomInt(2,6);
   } else if (s[i] == 1) {
     s[i] = getRandomInt(3,7);
   }

  });    

};
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a loop because I don't think there is a forEach in the code.org AppLab.

Answer (score -1):

```
    // check this out for size

var skill=function() {
   if (s[0] === 0) {
     s[0] = Random(2,6);
   } else if (s[0] === 1) {
     s[0] = Random(3,7);
   }

  }
```

Comment: @ Gamingpro welcome to SO and thank you for your answer. Can you provide more details why your answer is good and how it solve the question

Comment: @TamirKlein it correctly declares  the skill variable and uses (one of) the correct randomizer functions

Comment: if you have any more questions about my code, feel free to copy it into plunker

Comment: at http://next.plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next&preview